# Unseen Problem based on area of triangle

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC$, $BD=2CD$ and $AE=ED$, prove that $6\triangle ACE=\triangle ABC$[image]

If $A,X$ is joined such that $X$ is the mid point of $BC$ then:

$\triangle ABX=\triangle AXC$

Also,

$\triangle AEC=\triangle EDC$

now, what should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Use lemma:**

Let $\frac{AM}{MC}=\frac mn$. Then $$\frac{S_{AMX}}{S_{CMX}}=\frac{\frac12AM\cdot XD}{\frac12 MC \cdot XD}=\frac{AM}{MC}=\frac mn$$

**The proof of the problem:**

Let $S_{ACE}=x$. If $AE=ED$ then $S_{ACE}=S_{CED}=x$. Then $S_{ADC}=2x$. If $BD=2DC$, then $S_{ABD}=2S_{ADC}=4x$. Then $S_{ABC}=S_{ABD}+S_{ADC}=4x+2x=6x$

Comment: @ Roman83, your figure explanation is unclear to me as it doesn't match with my figure. Could you put it a bit clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Since $DC=\frac{1}{3} BC$ it follows that $\triangle ADC= \frac{1}{3} \triangle ABC$ since they have the same height on DC and BC.

$\triangle ACE = \triangle EDC$ , because $AE=ED$, and $\sin \angle AEC = \sin \angle DEC \Rightarrow \triangle ACE= \frac{1}{2} \triangle ADC = \frac{1}{6} \triangle ABC $

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the base into three equal parts means dividing the area of triangle in three equal parts. Here $\triangle ADC$ is one of the $3 $ parts.So $\triangle ADC=\frac{1}{3}\triangle ABC$

Now we have to prove that $\triangle AEC=\frac{1}{2}\triangle ADC$.As given the area has been divided into two equal parts by dividing the base AD into two equal parts ,hence proved .

Answer (score 0):

Then, combine $\triangle AEC$ and $\triangle DEC$ into $\triangle ADC$ whose area is then 2 parts if that of $\triangle AEC$ is 1 part. The process goes on.....

[image]